# Create a table dynamically using JSON keys and Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting the JSON response from a Ajax call like this below:

```
{"Key1":"Value1" , "Key2":"Value2" , "Key3":"Value3" , "Key4":"Value4" }
```

I need create a table like

```
KEYS  VALUES
Keys1 Value1
Keys2 Value2
Keys3 Value3
Keys4 Value4
```

I have used to read the above JSON string through this function below

```
var resData = {
   "Key1": "Value1",
   "Key2": "Value2",
   "Key3": "Value3",
   "Key4": "Value4",
};
JSON.parse(resData, function (k, v) {
   alert(k); // It shows Key value
   alert(v); // It shows value
});
```

I couldn't achieve to build using this function. So, please help me to tweak this code or with new code to build the HTML table dynamically using the JSON keys and Values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this html:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>KEY</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this jQuery script:

```
var resData = {"Key1":"Value1" , "Key2":"Value2" , "Key3":"Value3" , "Key4":"Value4" },
    $tbody = $('#myTable').find('tbody');

JSON.parse(resData, function (k, v) {
    $tbody.append('<tr><td>'+k+'</td><td>'+v+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: When the table renders on the page, it shows a extra [object Object] like{"Key1":"Value1" , "Key2":"Value2" , "Key3":"Value3" , "Key4":"Value4" ,"":"[object Object]"}.. Why it is coming like this? how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like...

```
var table = "<table>";
var resData = {"Key1":"Value1" , "Key2":"Value2" , "Key3":"Value3" , "Key4":"Value4" }
resData = JSON.parse(resData);
for(var k in resData ) {
table +="<tr><td>"+k+"</td><td>"+resData[k]+"</td></tr>";
});
table +="</table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way. Creates table dynamically

```
var table = $('<table/>').html('<thead><tr><th>KEYS</th><th>VALUES</th></tr></thead>').appendTo('body'),
    tbody = table.append('<tbody/>');
$.each(resData, function(key, value){
    tbody.append('<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/arra1kx2/)

---

**[EDIT]**

And in addition, there's an example of how to create a table from multidimensional objects (or/and arrays):

```js
var resData = {
    "John": {
        "Name":"John", 
        "Surname":"Doe",
        "Sex":"Mr.",
        "Age":"36",
        "About":{
            "Status":"Married",
            "Interests":[
                "Family",
                "Games",
                "Swimming",
                "Photography",
                "Football"
            ],
            "Work":"Web developer"
        }
    }
};

function parseToTable(obj, el){
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        var keyType = ($.isPlainObject(value) ? '{'+key+'}' : ($.isArray(value) ? '['+key+']' : key));
        var tr = $('<tr/>').html('<td>'+keyType+' :</td>').appendTo(el);
        if($.isPlainObject(value) || $.isArray(value)){
            parseToTable(value, $('<table/>').html('<thead><tr><th>KEY:</th><th>VALUE:</th></tr></thead>').appendTo(tr));
        }else{
            tr.append('<td>'+value+'</td>');
        }
    });
}

var table = $('<table/>').html('<thead><tr><th>KEY:</th><th>VALUE:</th></tr></thead>').appendTo('body');
parseToTable(resData, table.append('<tbody/>'));
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #929292;
    margin:8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ababab;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #929292;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    background:#fff;
    font-weight:normal;
}

th{
    background:#a9a9a9;
    color:white;
}
th:nth-child(1){
    text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(1){
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    text-align: right;

}
td:nth-child(2){
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
}

tr table thead tr th{
    font-size:12px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```